# If $\phi(v_1),...\phi(v_\rho)$ are linearly independent, show that $v_1,...,v_\rho$ are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\phi:V\rightarrow W$ be linear. Suppose that $v_1,...,v_\rho \in V$ are such that $\phi(v_1),...\phi(v_\rho)$ are linearly independent in $W$. Show that $v_1,...,v_\rho$ are linearly independent.

I know to be independent, no two distinct linear combinations of elements in the set can be equal vectors.

So, I guess that makes sense that if the outputs from a function are all linearly independent then the inputs would all be independent as well, but how can I put that explanation in a more technical way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $c_1v_1 + ... + c_nv_n = 0.$ Now applying $\phi$ to both sides we obtain, since $\phi$ is linear, $0 = \phi(0) = \phi(c_1v_1 + ... + c_nv_n) = c_1\phi(v_1) + ... + c_n\phi(v_n).$  Now since the images are linearly independent, it must be the case that $c_1 = c_2 = ... = c_n = 0.$ Therefore, $v_1 ... v_n$ are linearly independent.

Comment: OK, but you're going in circles in the second and third sentence. You should simply say "Now applying $\phi$ to both sides we obtain, since $\phi$ is linear, $0 = \phi(0) = \phi(c_1v_1 + ... + c_nv_n) = c_1 \phi(v_1) + ... + c_n \phi(v_n)$."

Comment: That does sound much better, I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try to prove the contrapositive: "If $\{v_i\}$ are linearly dependent, then $\{\phi(v_i)\}$ are linearly dependent."

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_n v_n = 0$. Then apply $\varphi$ to both sides to get $c_1 \varphi (v_1) + \cdots + c_n \varphi (v_n) = 0$ and now use the hypothesis that the images are linearly independent.